# Skrollr get scroll top position of a specific element

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, skrollr, autoscroll

I am working with the Skrollr Plugin. 
I am running jQuery 1.9.1 too.

I have found out that parallax pages are a lot of fun on a desktop with a mouse wheel to scroll. On an iPad or other touch devices nobody wants to scroll through that much animation, no matter how cool it is.. poor user experience. So what I decided to do is add two buttons. One on the middle right side and the other on the middle left side for the thumbs. You press the one on the right and you autoscroll to the next section. Vice versa for the left side.

Well instead of testing a bunch of different screen sizes and manually adding a bunch of values to an array and then having a script figure out what size screen it is and go through the custom array... I would rather have a function that looks up the IDs and grab the scrollTopPosition and push that into the array.

As far as the plugins documentation I have only seen this function. s.getScrollTop. That returns your current scroll position.

I tried the following commands:

```
document.getElementById('id').getBoundingClientRect();
document.getElementById('id').offsetTop;
$('#id').offset().top;
$("#id").position();
```

All gave me the wrong values when comparing to the `s.getScrollTop()` return value.

This is the last item in my icebox and I would love to knock it out today. Thank you for any help!

Comment: why not just add named anchors and use `#name` links?

Comment: Wouldnt that snap me to the position? I need to scroll to the position using the plugins s.animateTo() function.

Comment: Actually I never thought of that and I googled a little bit and I think I found someing @ https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-menu